# Video Streaming with DoubleTwist and VideoView

Tags: android

I have tried streaming a mp4 video with a video view that fails. However, with DoubleTwist it works. I want to embed my Custom Player in my application, and using a external player is not really an option. How can i do this ? What do you think could be a possible problem ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Whats the failure from logcat?

Comment: No Failiure its just shows a popup that wont allow it top play .

Comment: What does that say, and also look in logcat,  there will be something more definitive as to why your mp4 is failing.  I'm guessing that the file not set up for streaming (encode is wrong or MOOV atom is in the wrong place).

Comment: Also, its very likely that the root cause of your problem has already been asked here.  Take a look at the related posts (right column below the ads).